# Rails 4 manually creating migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is happening under the hood when executing this?

```
rails generate migration create_menu_categories_and_menu_items
```

Why can't I just create a file in the migrations directory? It seems I have to use the generate command in order for it to actually run, but the only file I see changed is the file created by the above command.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you need to get the time stamp at the beginning of the file name, so that rails can figure out that it's a "pending migration" and run it. It does this by storing the time stamp (or version in migration parlance) in a special database table (schema_migrations) and anything newer than the last run migration is pending.

Otherwise there's nothing special about the file itself

Answer (score 1):

You dont even have to create a separate migration file. You can just add a column to your table by adding the object to to your current migration class like this:

```
t.string :name
```

Then run a rake db:migrate

Hope this helps.